# What do tensor fields, both smooth and not smooth, correspond to?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, differential-forms, tensors, vector-bundles

My book is Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes by Loring W. Tu (I'll call this Volume 3), a sequel to both Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott (Volume 2) and An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu (Volume 1).

[Proposition 21.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k88ER.png) says smooth tensor fields $\tilde T$, defined as smooth sections of $T^{(a,b)}M$, i.e. elements of $\Gamma(T^{(a,b)}M)$, bijectively correspond to $C^{\infty}M$-multi-linear maps $T: (\Omega^1M)^a \times \mathfrak X(M)^b \to C^{\infty}M$

**Question:** What do tensor fields $\tilde S$, smooth or not, defined as sections, smooth or not, of $T^{(a,b)}M$, i.e. elements of $A(T^{(a,b)}M) := \{\text{all sections of} \ T^{(a,b)}M \}$, bijectively correspond to?

My thoughts: The set $A(M):=\{\text{all maps} \ f : M \to \mathbb R\}$ can be made into a ring such that $C^{\infty}M$ is a subring of $A(M)$ i.e. $A(M)$ becomes a ring that is a superring of $C^{\infty}M$. Similarly, we have that $O^1M$ and $\mathcal X(M)$, the smooth-or-not supersets of, respectively, $\Omega^1M$ and $\mathfrak X(M)$, can be made into $\mathbb R$-superspaces and $C^{\infty}M$-supermodules, of, respectively, $\Omega^1M$ and $\mathfrak X(M)$.

Then $\tilde S$ bijectively corresponds to:

1. Guess 1: some $C^\infty M$-linear $S_1: (\Omega^1M)^a \times \mathfrak X(M)^b \to A(M)$
2. Guess 2: some $A(M)$-linear $S_2: (O^1M)^a \times \mathcal X(M)^b \to A(M)$

---

Context:

1. I'm wondering what [Proposition 22.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Garx6.png) would be simply for $\omega$ and (thus) $\nabla_X\omega$ not necessarily smooth.
2. But I think we can think of the above question in terms of 1-forms $\omega$:

$\omega \in \Omega^1M$ if and only if $\hat{\omega}: \mathfrak X(M) \to C^{\infty}M$ is $C^{\infty}M$-linear, where  $\hat{\omega}(X) := \omega(X)$, where $\omega(X): M \to \mathbb R$, $\omega(X) \in C^{\infty}M$, $(\omega(X))(p) := \omega_p(X_p)$

Then, I think $\omega$, a 1-form on $M$, not necessarily smooth, bijectively corresponds to

- some $A(M)$-linear, $\hat{\omega}: \mathcal X(M) \to A(M)$
- or some $C^{\infty}M$-linear, $\hat{\omega}: \mathfrak X(M) \to A(M)$,

where, in either case, we still have $\hat{\omega}(X) := \omega(X)$ and $\omega(X): M \to \mathbb R$, not necessarily smooth, $(\omega(X))(p) := \omega_p(X_p)$

Comment: You should be able to prove that your second guess is correct quite easily - unlike the smooth case, you don't have to fumble around constructing smooth bump functions, and instead can use indicator functions of points.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks! You can answer if you want.

Comment: Presumably $\Omega^1M$ should be $(\Omega^1 M)^a$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess 2 is correct: rough tensor fields correspond to $A(M)$-multilinear maps (acting on rough vector fields/one-forms). Let's quickly prove it for one-forms.

Given a rough one-form $\omega \in O^1$, the corresponding map $\hat \omega:\mathcal X \to A$ defined by $(\hat \omega(V))_x = \omega(V_x)$ is $A$-linear since $$\hat \omega(fV)_x = \omega((fV)_x) = f(x)\omega (V_x)=(f\hat\omega(V))_x.$$

Conversely, if $\hat \omega : \mathcal X \to A$ is $A$-linear, then for any point $x$ the indicator function $1_x$ is in $A$; so by linearity we have $\hat \omega(1_xV) = 1_x \hat \omega(V).$ Evaluating this at $x$ we see that the value of $\hat \omega(V)$ at $x$ depends only on the value of $V$ at $x;$ so there is some $\omega_x : T_x \to \mathbb R$ such that $\hat \omega(V)_x = \omega(V_x)$ for all $V_x$. Gathering up these $\omega_x$ gives us the desired section $\omega \in O^1$.